# Need help to generate AccessToken with the code coming in redirect_uri from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

I need some help in generating the AccessToken in C#. After successfully authenticating from **login.microsoftonline.com** it is redirecting to redirect_uri provided in AzureAD. In the redirect_uri I have the **code** in the **querystring**. Using that code I want to generate the token but unable to do so. I followed below article to do so. But not much help i get. Can anyone please help me here. Any code snippet will be more helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user

Answer (score 1):

Sample code for this use-case in C# - RestSharp:

```
var client = new RestClient("https:<Authz server host>/oauth/token-request");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic <base64 encoded value for clientId:clientSecret>");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code");
request.AddParameter("code", "<code generated>");
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", "<redirect_uri value>");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content)
```

It is always easier to have Postman in this kind of scenario where you can build and test the entire flow of OAuth and also get code snippets generated by it.

Comment: Hi @Srinath Menon, Thank you for your time. Actually while trying from postman I am getting the error like "The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE."  Have tried to resolve but unable to do so. Any suggestion how to resolve this ?

Comment: Can you post the screenshot for Postman Authorization tab where the token is being generated?

Comment: Sorry I am not able to insert any image here to provide the screenshot. Is there any other way I can provide ?

Comment: @SunilM, it is quite impossible to arrive at any conclusion without the relevant data. Use dummy values in the Authorization tab and provide the relevant screenshots for review.

Comment: Thank you Srinath for your time. Now I am able to generate AccessToken through Postman (May be missing something earlier for which I was facing issue. Now I have created a new request endpoint which is working fine). But only concern is that not able to generate the AccessToken by using c#.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment

You can use the below code to generate access token using the authcode :

```
using System;
using RestSharp;
namespace GetTokenEx
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(getToken());
    }
    public static string getToken()
    {
       var restClient = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token");
       var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
       request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       request.AddParameter("client_id","client-id-used-to-generate-the-code");
       request.AddParameter("scope","scope-used-to-generate-the-code ");
       request.AddParameter("code","code-obtained-in-the-redirect-uri");
       request.AddParameter("redirect_uri","redirect-uri-used-to-generate-the-code ");
       request.AddParameter("grant_type"," authorization_code");
       request.AddParameter("client_secret","client-secret-of-app-registration");
       var response = restClient.Execute(request);
       return response.Content;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @RamaraoAdapa-MT Thanks for your time. I have tried above code. But facing the issue -- "The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE." Have tried to resolve but unable to do so. Have you come accross this error in your code ? Any idea how to resolve this ?

Comment: I have not come across this error in my code. Check if this helps : https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/08/performing-azure-ad-oauth2-authorization-code-grant-flow-with-pkce-in-postman/

Comment: Thank you. I had already tried all the settings provided in the given link. But no luck yet to resolve that.

Comment: What parameters are you using to generate the auth code?

Comment: I have provided everything mentioned under Authorization tab in Postman. Unable to share the screenshot here. But note that I have used all the parameters mentioned under Authorization tab in postman.

Comment: We can move this discussion to chat room. You can join using below link : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238801/c-aad-access-token

Comment: Do not have much reputation on SO to participate in chat section. That's why unable to participate there. (As per the SO policy one must have 20 reputation to participate in chat section)

Comment: I used this URL to generate the  code  : https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
&state=12345  Did you also use the  same?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was out of office for last few days. Anyway Yes I am using the above url to generate the code. Now I had tried to generate AccessToken by the use of Postman with the code I received from the above url call and is able to get the accessToken on Postman response. But not able to generate AccessToken through c# code.

Comment: Did you use the same code I suggested in the answer? Also, what error you are getting?

Comment: Yes I had used the same code that you had provided. Getting the error "The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE."  So I have changed the "grant_type" parameter value to "client_credentials". Now facing the issue "Application with Identifier 9d1a******** was not found in the directory Microsoft. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the adminstrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant........................... "

Comment: Is that app registration is present in your active directory tenant?

Comment: Yes this is present.

Comment: are you able to generate the access token using Postman. If yes, are you using the same body and headers as mentioned in the code?

Comment: Yes I am able to generate the AccessToken using Postman. Also used the same body and headers as mentioned. But one thing I notice In postman even if I am not passing the code/Modifying the code value to any value but still able to generate the AccessToken.

Comment: Can you add the screenshots of both postman and c# code requests for access token

Comment: Sorry, Not able to attach the screenshots here.

Comment: Add the URL of the screenshot in the comment or add the screenshots in the question