# Azure AD getting Access token - Bad Request

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, access-token

I have an app registered with User.read and User.ReadBasicAll API permission and I'm trying to get the access token via the authorization code grant. I get the authorization code after user consent but when I try to get the access token, I always get "400 Bad Request".

Below is the URL for getting the auth code :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize
?response_type=code
&client_id=my_client_id
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default+openid+offline_access+
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fzzzzzzzzzzzz.azurewebsites.net%2Flogin%2Fauthorized
&response_mode=query
&sso_reload=true
```

below is the C# function for getting the access token from the auth code above and here I'm getting HTTP 400 Bad Request. Any help citing the mistake here would be very helpful. Please note that I hard coded the sample values for better understanding.

```
public string GetAccessToken(string authCode)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                
                var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
                var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "my_client_id"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", "https://zzzzzzzzzzzz.azurewebsites.net/"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", authCode),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "mysecret")
             };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

                var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;


                string paramsForAccessToken = string.Empty;
                foreach (var item in pairs)
                {
                    paramsForAccessToken += item.Key + " = " + item.Value + "<br>";
                }
                result += "Request Content : " + content + "<br><br> <br>";
                result += "Status code " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + "<br><br>";
                result += "Response Reason Phrase" + response.ReasonPhrase + "<br><br>";
                result += "Response content" + response.Content.ToString()+ "<br><br>";
                result += "Response headers" + response.Headers + "<br><br>";
                result += "Request message" + response.RequestMessage+ "<br><br>";
                result += paramsForAccessToken;
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    result += response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
                


            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblAccessToken.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
            return result;

        }
```

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70151161/255562) suggested below has the same issue

[image]

Here is the output of response.ToString()

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
  Pragma: no-cache
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
  x-ms-request-id: da55d4ba-3ccb-45f9-81c9-9f7394f12402
  x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.12231.8 - EUS ProdSlices
  Set-Cookie: fpc=AudRQ4x4W7RBpZY5YwJyyR_kb8VOAQAAAA_4NtkOAAAA; expires=Wed, 29-Dec-2021 16:34:25 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
  Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly
  Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly
  Date: Mon, 29 Nov 2021 16:34:24 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
  Content-Length: 477
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with postman? You can refer this thread to fetch the access token from auth code using c# : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69738536/need-help-to-generate-accesstoken-with-the-code-coming-in-redirect-uri-from-azur/69750680#69750680

Comment: The 400 bad request implies that the Auth code being used is not valid. Does the same test from Postman works successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment.

I am able to fetch the access token successfully.

You can use the below code to get the access token:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace GetAccessToken
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(getToken());
        }
        public static string getToken()
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                var uri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0";
                var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "my_client_id"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "mysecret")
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "authorization_code"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", "authCode"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default openid offline_access")
                };

                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

                var response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;

                
                string paramsForAccessToken = string.Empty;
                foreach (var item in pairs)
                {
                    paramsForAccessToken += item.Key + " = " + item.Value + "<br>";
                }
                result += "Request Content : " + content + "<br><br> <br>";
                result += "Status code " + response.StatusCode.ToString() + "<br><br>";
                result += "Response Reason Phrase" + response.ReasonPhrase + "<br><br>";
                result += "Response content" + response.Content.ToString() + "<br><br>";
                result += "Response headers" + response.Headers + "<br><br>";
                result += "Request message" + response.RequestMessage + "<br><br>";
                result += paramsForAccessToken;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. What is different in yours?

Comment: I added the version in the  uri. Also using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;

Comment: Same issue. Please see my updated question with the output of your function.

Comment: Can you print the response and see if it is null or having any data?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: Even I faced the same error when I edited your code. When I wrote the code from the scratch as mentioned in the answer, I was able to fetch the access token. Can you try once?